# What is the music that plays in episode 46 of Shippuden

Tags: naruto, music

What is the music that [plays in episode 46](https://youtu.be/vkPEJQz2f9I?t=397) of Shippuden?

Answer (score 2):

Found it.
Sai theme Naruto Shippuden - [**Sai theme song**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enD0LhHJ8Gw)